# How to get inheritance entity by using joined sub entity in jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

Writing the case it will be more simple to explain.

I am using Seam 2.3.1 v Hibernate JPA 2.0 and in our project. I have a base `Person` Entity Class.

```
@Entity
@Name("person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person extends BaseEntity  {

    private String name;
    private String surName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    // getter & setters
}
```

And I have 3 more Entity extends from Person as `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`: `Personel`, `Musteri`, `DisPaydas`

```
@Entity
@Name("personel")
public class Personel extends Person {

    private String appellation; 
    // getter & setters
}
```

I want to List personels, musteris and dispaydas in my bean however when I set them in my Group Entity, I want to save them as Person.

In fact in DB there is no difference between person_id and personel_id, they are same. However when I listing it, they are `List<Personel>`

In summary:

I want to get `List<Person>` from `List<Personel>`
or `Person` from `Personel` object.

Comment: @DiscriminatorColumn ?

Comment: The JOINED type expects the same Id column in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to define an `@Id` and `@Column` in the `Person` class for the `person_id`.

However, since the column has a different name in the child entity, you'll need to change it using an [`@AttributeOverride`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html) to point to the `personel_id` `@Column`.

It couldn't hurt to use a `@DiscriminatorColumn` in the parent and `@DiscriminatorValue` in the children, but I don't think Hibernate requires those.

Comment: There is `@Id` for the `Person` entity comes from `BaseEntity`. But, how can I get `List<Person>` from `List<Personels>` ?